# How do I get understandable DecisionTreeClassifier output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

2 issues that I have done a couple hours of research on without resolution.  When I make a DecisionTreeClassifier tree using "tree.plot_tree(my_model) with 2 levels I can clearly see the tree.  The variables are presented as X[55], and I haven't found how to replace the X[55] with the variable name, like "temperature".  When I set the levels to 3 or above and the plot is impossible to read.  Making it bigger just makes the blurry characters bigger, but still blurry.

Here is some code:

```
X = df.drop ( ['target_var'], axis = 1 )
y = df [ [ 'target_var' ] ]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth = 3 )

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)

tree.plot_tree(model )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times you want to change the size of matplotlib plots using the rc params values like figure size and font size. You can also change the dpi if you want to zoom in and out a lot.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [14, 10] # 14 by 10 inch
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 15
```

As far as setting the variable names, you can do this with the feature_names argument, simply pass the names as a list of strings.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html

Comment: This will also change anything that uses these values, which should include the sklearn libraries plotting.